# How to Convert Hashmap to ArrayList

Tags: java, json, firebase

```
private void showResult(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(mJsonString);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON);


            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = item.getString(TAG_ID);
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put(TAG_ID, id);

                String aa = hashMap.get("user_no");

                mArrayList.add(hashMap);
            }

        }
    }
```

I want to convert Data in Hashmap to ArrayList or other thing

I tried other way but can't

Comment: And what is other way you have tried?

Comment: create a composite object, with two variables: key and content. iterate over your map, and for each element, create an instance of it's key and value, and store those in your List

Comment: Your code seems to create an `ArrayList<HashMap>`. Is it not what you wanted?

Comment: I want to data in hashmap to ArrayList or other things

Answer (score 0):

Add below Lines.

```
List<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(TAG_ID, id);

list.add(hashMap)
```

Comment: congratulations ... you only lost half of the information

Comment: Example { index 0 : TAG_ID = 1, index 1 : TAG_ID = 2 , index 2 : TAG_ID  =3}

Comment: then add Hashmap into ArrayList

Comment: list[0]=1 , list[1]=2 , list[2]=3

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: so now we have a List containing the hashmap, it wasn't converted to one